# TMLanguage, what does captures do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am working on a tm language project for vscode and I'm wondering what the `captures` property on a pattern does exactly.

I can't seem to figure out what the indexes of the captures object stand for and I can't find any information on it online.

**Example**:

```
{
    "match": "(group 1)(group2)"
    "captures": {
        "0": {
             "name": "Name of first capture group? What does 0 mean here?"
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: capture `0` means the whole string, it is only useful in `beginCaptures` and `endCaptures`, you use `captures` in other cases if you need to match a lot before the actual text (variable lookbehind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "captures" key is documented here, in the "Rule Keys" section (12.3):

https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars

The name is not the name of the first capture group.  It is just a string that specifies the name of the style to apply to the characters that were matched by that capture group.  When I say "capture group", I am referring to a matching left paren and right paren in your regular expression.

Using the "captures" key is a relatively complex way to assign style names to characters in the document.  It allows you to specify different styles to different portions of the text matched by the regular expression.  A simpler way is to just use the "name" key, which will apply the style to all of the matched text.